# How do I collect all the topics that are owned by the members of the groups I am a member of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, ruby-on-rails-4

This may be tough for me to explain, so if it's not clear just let me know so I can edit as needed!

I have the following example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
  has_many :memberships
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

#join model between User and Group
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :source => :user
  has_many :topics, :through => :members
end
```

The problem I'm having is that I am trying to create a feed (`@feed_topics`) of all topics that are owned by all the members of the groups I am a member of, and I'm driving myself a little nuts.

Should I try to make this happen using associations, or make an instance method in my User model that has some ActiveRecord/SQL to union all the groups' members' topics into one ActiveRecord::Relation object?

My goal is to write `current_user.feed_topics` in my controller's action.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what a GroupUser is supposed to represent? And what does it mean that a User has many GroupUsers?

Comment: Hi @Rebitzele, I edited my question to clarify. While I'm here - a GroupUser is basically a membership object joining various Users with various Groups. You can probably answer your 2nd question yourself now :) Hope that helps. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not explaining earlier! The idea was to utilize 'Nested has_many_through's in order to get to your feed topics. This concept is documented here under the heading 'Nested Associations': http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html.
Let me know if this still is unclear (or if it doesn't work).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :membership
  has_many :group_members, :through => :groups, :source => :member
  has_many :feed_topics, :through => :group_members, :source => :topic
end
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do there. I think I need more of an explanation. I'm going to tweak the GroupUsers model and it just call it Memberships for now to make this more simple. Hopefully no one is currently working on an answer!

Comment: I see where I was a little confused. I was wondering why you had the `has_many :group_members, :through => :groups, :source => :member` in the User model, but I don't blame ya! Maybe it could have worked both ways. For understanding, I put it in the Group model b/c I felt like it made sense to do `@group.members`.

Answer (score 1):

So far these are the final versions of the models from the original question (topic and membership did not change):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  has_many :feed_topics, :through => :groups, :source => :member_topics
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :source => :user
  has_many :member_topics, :through => :members, :source => :topics
end
```

I am testing right now by adding more groups and members to see if it pulls in all the other members' topics of other groups.

EDIT: things seem to be working ok.

EDIT2: one little problem I had was seeing duplicate topics because a member was in multiple groups. I learned about `:uniq => true` and it saved the day.